# json serializing linq result in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I have some code that returns linq result (I even tried to add `ToList()`)

I see the collection OK

[image]

but when I get out of the function body, 
another abstraction layer is added

[image]

at the end ewhen I return the client the result

it gets:

"{ apps = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[\u003c\u003ef__AnonymousType1`4[System.String,System.String,\u003c\u003ef__AnonymousType0`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String],System.Object]], Status = succeeded }"

How can I serialize the linq result properly?

**Update**
Beforehand, it used to work without calling `JSON()`

```
    public object GetAppsData()
    {

        var appsData = new List<AppData>();
        using (IDataReader dr = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase().ExecuteReader("usp_AppsData_GetAll"))
        {

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                appsData.Add(new AppData()
                {
                    AppGuid = (Guid)dr["AppGuid"],
                    AppName = (string)dr["AppName"],
                    ClientAppID = dr["ClientAppID"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["ClientAppID"],
                    Url = dr["Url"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["Url"],
                    DisplayName = dr["DisplayName"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["DisplayName"],
                    AppDesc = dr["AppDesc"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["AppDesc"],
                    PrivacyPolicyUrl = dr["PrivacyPolicyUrl"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["PrivacyPolicyUrl"],
                    TermsOfUseUrl = dr["TermsOfUseUrl"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["TermsOfUseUrl"],
                    //Platform = dr["Platform"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["Platform"],
                    //MaxVersion = dr["MaxVersion"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["MaxVersion"],
                    LocalizationKey = dr["LocalizationKey"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (string)dr["LocalizationKey"],
                    Compatibility = dr["Compatibility"] == DBNull.Value ? null : jss.Deserialize<object>((string)dr["Compatibility"])

                });

            }
        }

        var appsDataJson = appsData.Select(GenerateAppsDataClientResponse);

        return new { apps = appsDataJson, Status = "succeeded" };
    }



    private object GenerateAppsDataClientResponse(AppData a)
    {
        object result;
        if (a.Compatibility == null)
        {
            result = new
            {
                id = a.ClientAppID,
                url = a.Url,
                optionsDialog = new
                {
                    displayName = a.DisplayName,
                    appDesc = a.AppDesc,
                    privacyPolicyUrl = a.PrivacyPolicyUrl,
                    termsOfUseUrl = a.TermsOfUseUrl
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // this line throws NullReferenceException
            result = new
            {
                id = a.ClientAppID,
                url = a.Url,
                optionsDialog = new
                {
                    displayName = a.DisplayName,
                    appDesc = a.AppDesc,
                    privacyPolicyUrl = a.PrivacyPolicyUrl,
                    termsOfUseUrl = a.TermsOfUseUrl
                },
                compatibility = a.Compatibility
            };
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAppsData()
    {
        try
        {
           AppsDataManager appsData = new AppsDataManager();
           object adr =  appsData.GetAppsData();
           return this.JsonpOptional(adr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Application.Error("ClientDataController.GetSettings", ex);
            return this.JsonpOptional(new { Status = "failed", Reason = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cryptic datatype you see in the debugger is just the classname of the anonymous class you return with the `new` keyword.

Your main problem is, that you have to return a `JsonResult` and not the plain object. And don't forget to specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. Otherwise you will get an exception when returning JSON Data to a HTTP GET request:

```
return Json(new { apps = appsDataJson, Status = "succeeded" },
                 JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: for some odd reason the code recognize JsonResult but not Json() function. Why?

Comment: @EladBenda this is a method of the `Controller` base class from which your controller class should inherit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: stange, it used to work without `JSON()` call. see me update.

Comment: What do you want to tell me? You return `this.JsonpOptional(adr)` whatever that function might do...

Comment: no, no
at this line `object adr =  appsData.GetAppsData();` when I debug I see the string corectly whereas after my change I see in debug `System.Collections.Generic.List1[\u003c\u003ef__AnonymousType14[System.String,System.String,\u003c\u003ef__AnonymousType04[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String],System.Object` already

Comment: Usually, the handler denies any response for a GET request. So, you need to mention JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet.